# Add A Value to Rows And Cells In WPF

Tags: wpf

I was Developing a program with datagridview.
I need some help with Adding Values to Rows And Cells:

My code:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < 0x18; i++)
            {
                this.dataview1.UpdateDefaultStyle();
               this.dataview1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = i;
                this._dataview1[i].Cells[1].Value = GetName(i);
                Application.DoEvents();
            }
```

It dont work i get this as error:System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid does not contain Rows.
Same error with the cells. It works fine in c#.
My wpf code;

```
<Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
    <DataGrid x:Name="dataview1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="337" Width="809">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Client"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Name"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Please help me!
i hope i made this clear enough.

Comment: I don't see any code where you add rows to 'dataview1'. Are you sure the control has rows before your code is called?

Comment: @AndrewMack
I already tryed: 
     try
            {
                this.dataview1.IsEnabled = true;
                this.dataview1.RowCount = 0x18;
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Connection Failed.");
            }

Comment: @Christos92, check [this](http://wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html) tutorial first

Comment: @dzkozl Thanks but it wasnt wat i was searching for!

Comment: Using WinForms methodology on WPF controls makes it much more complicated if not, in some cases, impossible. When you work with WPF you use bindings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this . WPF has Magic Bindings

**You just need to add item to the collection(your source) WPF Bindings and DataGrid will Add Rows for you**

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
<DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Client" Binding="{Binding Client}" />
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />

</DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The ViewModel/CodeBehind

```
public class MyClients
 {

public string Name { get; set; }       
public string Client{ get; set; }

}

ObservableCollection<MyClients>  Customers=new ObservableCollection<MyClients>();

// Add data to the customer collection , as it is OBSERVABLE collection its notify when you add/remove item in OB. Collection
```

**On you add portion **

```
       for (int i = 0; i < 0x18; i++)
        {
            Customers.Add(new MyClients(){Client="value",Name="value"});
        }

**Collection Updated the datagrid also will be updated**
```

See Reference
[Link1](http://wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html)

[link2](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/datagrid-in-wpf/)

[link 3](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/datagrid-control/details-row/)

Comment: Thanks It works bud:)
i edited little the code because i had a value at Name:

  public string getname1(int client)
        {

            byte[] buffer = new byte[20];
            PS3.GetMemory(0x178646c, buffer);
            string names = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);
            names = names.Replace("\0", "");
            return names;
        }

Answer (score 0):

Updated code is here...

```
<DataGrid  x:Key="dg" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
<DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Company" Binding="{Binding Company}" />

</DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

ViewModel code is here...

```
public class Employee


{

public string Name { get; set; }       
public string Company{ get; set; }

}
ObservableCollection<Employee>  Customers=new ObservableCollection<Employee>();
for (int i = 0; i < 0x18; i++)
        {
            Emp.Add(new Employee(){Name="Kalsa",Company="Google"});
        }
         dg.ItemsSource=Emp;
```